# SQL query for a search engine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My project is based on Questions and Answers (stackoverflow style).

I need to allow users to search for previously asked questions.

The **Questions** table would be like this:

```
Questions
-------------------------------------------------
id                 questions
-------------------------------------------------
1                  How to cook pasta?
2                  How to Drive a car?
3                  When did Napoleon die?
```

Now when I'm going to write something to search for, I would write something like this:

```
When did Brazil win the world cup?
```

Let's say I'm gonna **split** this **String** on spaces, into an **array of Strings**.

What is the best **SELECT** SQL query to fetch all questions containing those Strings, ignoring upper case and lower case for each word, and sorting the results by the less mentioned word, why?

Because there will be so many questions which will contain **When,and,will,how**,etc.. , but not so many questions which will have **Brazil**, so **Brazil** would be like the **Key Word**.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What about full text search?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really don't want to be doing this in raw SQL.

I suggest you look into the full-text search options for your database, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) might be a good place to start.

Comment: I tried to execute a query which has [WHERE CONTAINS], but then I found out that the column is not full-text indexed, and the Full-Text index option is greyed out in Visual Studio 2010, I can't enable it, even after using a query such as [exec sp_fulltext_database 'enable']

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you have full-text indexes and the match() select function which allow just this, 
in SQL Server you should use the function Contains() 
Find more info on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your option is not the best one. Take a look at open source Apache Solr project. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Solr is a standalone enterprise search server with a REST-like API. You put documents in it (called "indexing") via XML, JSON, CSV or binary over HTTP. You query it via HTTP GET and receive XML, JSON, CSV or binary results.

- Advanced Full-Text Search Capabilities Optimized for High Volume Web
- Traffic Standards Based Open Interfaces - XML, JSON and HTTP
- Comprehensive HTML Administration Interfaces Server statistics
- exposed over JMX for monitoring Linearly scalable, auto index
- replication, auto failover and recovery Near Real-time indexing
- Flexible and Adaptable with XML configuration Extensible Plugin
  Architecture

Take a look at Detailed Features and aspecialy Query section. There all you need for your app.